# google app engine python get_by_id does not function

Tags: python, google-app-engine

first time post and new to google app engine!

i can't for the life of me figure out why my attempts to access an object using Model.get_by_id does not function.

my test data is populated and i can verify the output as commented. i can confirm the ID of the data in the Datastore viewer... but attempts to use that ID fail to return the object.

```
    namespace_manager.set_namespace('myNamespace')

    for t in models.MyClass.all().fetch(100):
        print t.key().id() # prints the key and verified in the Datastore Viewer
        print t.date # prints the date

        myClassInstance = models.MyClass.get_by_id(t.key().id()) # never finds the object
        if tour is None:
            print "MyClass instance not found"
```

so output is

```
    6
    2012-04-24 20:47:13.537000
    MyClass instance not found
    27
    2012-04-24 20:47:13.605000
    MyClass instance not found
    29
    2012-04-24 20:47:13.611000
    MyClass instance not found
    31
    2012-04-24 20:47:13.617000
    MyClass instance not found
```

note that this is not a root entity and has children as well... but shouldn't the MyClass.get_by_id method return the correct object?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are creating your entities with a parent/ancestor you need to provide that to the `get_by_id` function too.

```
entity = MyModel(parent = parentkey,
                 name   = 'somename')
entity.put()

entity_by_id = MyModel.get_by_id(entity.key().id(), parent = parentkey)
```

Comment: and what if its several layers down in the hierarchy? i'm getting the impression that the whole ancestor thing is strictly for entity grouping as there seems to be plenty of examples of entities storing their parents keys. i'm using namespaces to split the data so i may as well give up on the ancestor thing and just store keys or reference properties?

Comment: even layers down that parent will still be a parent of the entities in that entity group.